# import error: No module named "TkTreectrl"

Tags: python, tkinter, module, pip, listbox

I'm building my first Tkinter GUI, and I need to create a multi-column Listbox using TKtreectrl, but when importing the module I get this error, import error: No module named "TkTreectrl".
How to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed the module?

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for the replay, i can't find it at pycharm python interpreter, is there another way to install it

Comment: in cmd: `pip install module_name` for windows (where _module_name_ is obviously what the module is called as a pip package)

Comment: @Matiiss I appreciate your response I tried this and got an error          
C:\Users\user> pip install tktreectrl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tktreectrl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tktreectrl

Comment: it could be that when installing through pip it is not called `tktreectrl`, could be some other name like mentioned in the answer about linux, try using that as the `module_name`, also does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980669/installing-tkintertreectrl-on-windows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+tktreectrl

Comment: @Matiiss, thanks for your response, I want to install the library from its online repository. But I don't know where to install it, I'm using pycharm on windows 10, thanks in advance. I appreciate your cooperation.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're on Linux, you can install it via this command

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-tktreectrl
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, I am using windows 10.